# Rails safety_assured and rubocop disagreement on drop column migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, rubocop

In my Rails project I am using `safety_assured` and `rubocop` gems simultaneously. I intend to run a simple migration to delete a column, something along the lines of:

```rb
# db/migrate/...
+ class RemoveEnabledFromUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
+   def up
+     #safety_assured do
+       remove_column :users, :enabled
+     #end
+   end
+ 
+   def down
+     safety_assured do
+       add_column :users, :enabled, :boolean, default: true
+     end
+   end
+ end

# db/schema.rb
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    # ...
    t.string "name", null: false
-   t.boolean "enabled", default: true
    # ...
  end

# app/models/User.rb
  class User < ApplicationRecord
+   self.ignored_columns += ["enabled"]
    # ...
  end
```

The `safety_assured` gem is informing me that I should include `self.ignored_columns` in the model, and rubocop is saying that I should remove since it does not exist in the schema (`Rails/UnusedIgnoredColumns`).

I'm not experienced in Rails, but I assume ActiveRecord infers the schema from querying the database (MySQL/PostgreSQL) and that `db/schema.rb` is just a helper for other things (seeding dev databases for example). So there is a danger of the User schema changing unexpectedly while the server is running.

Is it safe to omit `ignored_columns` in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `ignored_columns` in the same commit (deploy) as removing the column does not add anything.

Assuming your deploy process does not differ much from the standard.

With the current implementation, when you deploy your code, first the migrations will run. The old code will still be running and serving requests in order to avoid downtime.

When the column drops, this will be a surprise to Rails (database is different than it was just a moment ago) and errors might be raised.

After deploy finishes, the column is no longer there and `ignored_columns` is indeed useless as Rubocop suggests.

The correct approach would be to first add `ignored_columns` for the columns you intend to remove and deploy that.

Then and only then add the migration to remove the column and remove `ignored_columns` in the same commit. Then deploy that.

Now with the first deploy Rails will start ignoring the column and you don't have to consider it anymore in your code, but it will still be there in the database in order to not break during the deploy.

The 2nd deploy is cleanup which will remove the column (already ignored so no errors), and remove the `ignored_columns` (not needed since column is gone).

Both [strong_migrations](https://github.com/ankane/strong_migrations) (safety_assured) and Rubocop are correct here. You are just misunderstanding strong migrations. I suggest you re-read their README.md. They tell you to:

> Be sure to ignore the column:
>
> ...
>
> **Deploy the code**, then wrap this step in a safety_assured { ... }
> block.

Comment: From what I gather of your deploy description I presume "your deploy process does not differ much from the standard" is false in my case and this logic does not apply, as my migrations run after the deploy and not before. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: There you have your answer. Your set-up depends on the column being ignored and the migration to remove it with the column still being ignored. Because your deployment process is non-standard, Rubocop defaults do not handle this case. I would simply ignore Rubocop's suggestion in this case.